# Sorting values of a specific index in a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a card game for an assignment. This is the final part of it.

I need to sort

```
Player 1 has won with 16 cards
Player 2 has won with 18 cards
Player 3 has won with 16 cards
Player 4 has won with 20 cards
Player 5 has won with 18 cards
Player 6 has won with 26 cards
Player 7 has won with 22 cards
Player 8 has won with 16 cards
Player 9 has won with 18 cards
Player 10 has won with 24 cards
```

Into

```
Player 6 has won with 24 cards
Player 10 has won with 24 cards
Player 7 has won with 22 cards
Player 4 has won with 20 cards
Player 2 has won with 18 cards
```

So I need to create a leaderboard for the top 5 winners (players with the most cards). The text above is the desired output. By the way I have to output this leaderboard in an external text file.

What I have tried:

I tried to format the raw text as such:

```
18 cards:Player 3 has won with 16 cards:Player 4 has won with 20 cards:Player 5 has won with 18 cards:Player 6 has won with 26 cards:Player 7 has won with 22 cards:Player 8 has won with 16 cards:Player 9 has won with 18 cards:Player 10 has won with 24 cards:
```

After doing this I split this output by every colon and printed the variable with which I split the output.

My code:

```
filereader = open("winner.txt", "r")
for everyline in filereader:
    splittingvariable = everyline.split(":")
    print(splittingvariable)
filereader.close()
```

The output:

```
['player1 has won with 16 cards', 'player2 has won with 18 cards', 'player3 has won with 16 cards', 'player4 has won with 20 cards', 'player5 has won with 18 cards', 'player6 has won with 26 cards', 'player7 has won with 22 cards', 'player8 has won with 16 cards', 'player9 has won with 18 cards', 'player10 has won with 24 cards', '']
```

After this however I didn't know what to do.  I did more to try and solve this than what I showed but most of them just ended up in errors.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas/ways to solve this problem.

Comment: _After this however I didn't know what to do._ Have you tried doing any research for something like "Python parse value from string" ?

Comment: I guess, the line "Player 6 has won with 24 cards" should read "Player 6 has won with 26 cards", right?

Comment: Yes @jottbe, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clean up the empty string element in your final list, then use the following code:

```
res = ['player1 has won with 16 cards', 'player2 has won with 18 cards', 'player3 has won with 16 cards', 'player4 has won with 20 cards', 'player5 has won with 18 cards', 'player6 has won with 26 cards', 'player7 has won with 22 cards', 'player8 has won with 16 cards', 'player9 has won with 18 cards', 'player10 has won with 24 cards']

res.sort(key = lambda x: x.split()[4], reverse = True)

print(res[:5])
```

Output:

```
['player6 has won with 26 cards', 
'player10 has won with 24 cards', 
'player7 has won with 22 cards', 
'player4 has won with 20 cards', 
'player2 has won with 18 cards']
```

which is, I hope, what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to sort a list of strings, but use some part of the string to sort, rather than just full string itself.

`sorted(lines)` on its own won't work, as it sorts the entire string.

However, the `sorted()` function allows you to pass a function as a `key` to sort items`.

You can create a lambda function to extract the relevant part of the string to sort on.

I've also used the `reverse` keyword to sort in the descending order.

```
list_input = [
    'Player 1 has won with 16 cards',
    'Player 2 has won with 18 cards',
    'Player 3 has won with 16 cards',
    'Player 4 has won with 20 cards',
    'Player 5 has won with 18 cards',
    'Player 6 has won with 26 cards',
    'Player 7 has won with 22 cards',
    'Player 8 has won with 16 cards',
    'Player 9 has won with 18 cards',
    'Player 10 has won with 24 cards',
]

sorted(list_input, key=lambda x: str(x.split(" ")[-2]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sorted function with key= parameter that extracts the number of cards from each line:

```
gameOutcomes = "Player 3 has won with 16 cards:Player 4 has won with 20 cards:Player 5 has won with 18 cards:Player 6 has won with 26 cards:Player 7 has won with 22 cards:Player 8 has won with 16 cards:Player 9 has won with 18 cards:Player 10 has won with 24 cards"
leaders = sorted(gameOutcomes.split(":"),
                 key=lambda L:int(L.split()[-2]),
                 reverse=True)

for leader in leaders[:5]:
   print(leader)

# Player 6 has won with 26 cards
# Player 10 has won with 24 cards
# Player 7 has won with 22 cards
# Player 4 has won with 20 cards
# Player 5 has won with 18 cards
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of the above with three lines of code:

```
with open("winner.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    content = sorted([line.strip() for line in inFile], key=lambda elem: int(elem.split(' ')[5]), reverse=True)
    print("\n".join(content[:5]), end="")
```

You can read the contents of the file line by line and sort them, based on the number of cards which you will find by splitting each line and getting the 6th element of it.

The result will be:

```
Player 6 has won with 26 cards
Player 10 has won with 24 cards
Player 7 has won with 22 cards
Player 4 has won with 20 cards
Player 2 has won with 18 cards
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file in as a string you can use:

```
print('\n'.join([i[1] for i in sorted([(match.split()[-2], match) for match in open("winner.txt")], reverse = True)][:5]))
```

results in:

```
Player 6 has won with 26 cards
Player 10 has won with 24 cards
Player 7 has won with 22 cards
Player 4 has won with 20 cards
Player 9 has won with 18 cards
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
txt='''\
Player 1 has won with 16 cards
Player 2 has won with 18 cards
Player 3 has won with 16 cards
Player 4 has won with 20 cards
Player 5 has won with 18 cards
Player 6 has won with 26 cards
Player 7 has won with 22 cards
Player 8 has won with 16 cards
Player 9 has won with 18 cards
Player 10 has won with 24 cards'''

import re 

>>> sorted(txt.splitlines(), key=lambda l: -int(re.findall(r'(\d+)\D*$', l)[0]))
['Player 6 has won with 26 cards', 'Player 10 has won with 24 cards', 'Player 7 has won with 22 cards', 'Player 4 has won with 20 cards', 'Player 2 has won with 18 cards', 'Player 5 has won with 18 cards', 'Player 9 has won with 18 cards', 'Player 1 has won with 16 cards', 'Player 3 has won with 16 cards', 'Player 8 has won with 16 cards']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a bunch of approaches in mind

### Cmd Line

This would be the easier way to solve your problem of figuring out top five winners from a text file.
You can use this from your terminal

```
sort -n -k 6 raw.txt | head -n 5 > winner.txt
```

**sort**: *-k column*: Sorts by kth column and *-n*: Use numerical sort.
**head**: *-n column*: Returns you the top n columns

### Cmd Line + Python

But say for some reason like taking a custom user input, you want to use a python script (Though that can be done via a bash script also).
You can use

```
import os

def sort_data(input_file, output_file):
    cmd = 'sort -n -r -k 6 {} | head -n 5 > {}'.format(input_file, output_file)
    os.system(cmd)

def main():
    INPUT_FILE = input('Enter Input File\n')
    OUTPUT_FILE = input('Enter Output File')

    sort_data(INPUT_FILE, OUTPUT_FILE)

main()
```

### Python

**Note:** This only works if you have unix/linux as your os

You can always use this for the `sort_data` function

```
def sort_data(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as fp:
        input_data = fp.read().splitlines()

    with open(output_file, 'w') as fp:
        sorting_key = lambda x: str(x.split(" ")[5])
        sorted_data = sorted(input_data, key=sorting_key, reverse=True)
        no_of_winners = 5
        output_data = '\n'.join(sorted_data[:no_of_winners]) + '\n'
        fp.write(output_data)
```

`sorted` takes an iterator (list in this case) with a `key` being a function (`lambda` is a shorthand way for writing simple functions) and `reverse` controls the sorting order

You will need to manually add `\n`. Without them if you try to write to the file like `fp.write(''.join(sorted_data[:no_of_winners]))` you would end up with this in your file

`Player 6 has won with 26 cardsPlayer 10 has won with 24 cardsPlayer 7 has won with 22 cardsPlayer 4 has won with 20 cardsPlayer 2 has won with 18 cards`